# Does the miner transaction (of a block reward) get sent to a miner's stealth address?

Tags: stealth-address

Does the miner transaction (of a block reward) get sent to a miner's stealth address? (Or to the public address of the miner)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still a stealth address but the amount is not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The coinbase transaction, which is the type of transaction created through the successful mining of a block, is very similar to a regular transaction. The outputs are generated such that the miner's wallet can scan for incoming transactions in the usual way. Thus, the miner's wallet combines the wallet's private view key with the transaction public key in order to detect the presence of outputs destined for that wallet.